# Using Clean URLs in RESTful API

Tags: php, rest

"Clean URLs" also known as "RESTful URLs" are user-friendly, purely structural, and do not contain a query string. Instead they contain only the path of the resource.

ie: "http://twitter.com/users/show/"+username+".json"

**Questions about server-side functionality:**

1. Do I need to make a unique server-side API script for each directory?
2. Can I forward all requests to just one script if so how do I
   pull useful information from the Clean URL structure ($_GET['url_structure'])?
3. Why does twitter call to a .json file
   that surely doesn't exist. It must get generated on request. How
   does this work? This leads me to believe that the answer to question
   2 is yes.

Comment: Clean urls have nothing to do with REST apis. They're just a nice way to prettify urls that would otherwise have ugly query strings.  They're generally implemented using mod_rewrite to take the clean url and internally transmogrify it back to a query-string version.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**1)** Not if you use a RESTful framework like [RecessPHP](http://www.recessframework.org/) or if you use a mod_rewrite rule in your .htaccess file to redirect all API requests to a single PHP file (known as the front controller).

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/api/ api.php
```

**api.php**

```
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  //this would be /users/show/abc.json
```

---

**2)** You can use the rewrite module of apache to redirect all api requests to a special PHP file that handles them. Depending on your apache configuration, the original requested (RESTful) url will be stored in a server variable in PHP, I believe it's `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Of course you could also just pass along a `$_GET[]` variable to PHP that contained the RESTful url.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/api/([^\.]+).(xml|json|atom) api.php?url=$1&type=$2
```

**api.php**

```
$request_parts = explode('/', $_GET['url']); // array('users', 'show', 'abc')
$file_type     = $_GET['type'];

$output = get_data_from_db(); //Do your processing here
                              //You can outsource to other files via an include/require

//Output based on request
switch($file_type) {
    case 'json':
        echo json_encode($output);
        break;
    case 'xml':
        echo xml_encode($output); //This isn't a real function, but you can make one
        break;
    default:
        echo $output;
}
```

---

**3)** Twitter (and many other APIs) use this because it is a convenient way of supplying the format that an application expects back from an API. All of the API requests are rerouted to a single PHP file which handles creating all the files and echoing their contents to the output. The file is never actually stored on the server (unless it is cached).

---

**Good Resources**

- [mod_rewrite, a beginner's guide](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite)
- [Create a REST API with PHP](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/)
- [Recess PHP Framework | Tutorials](http://www.recessframework.org/section/tutorials)

---

A note on RecessPHP. It's certainly a great tool and I would encourage you look at it (maybe at its source to get an idea of how it processes things), but that said, it seems a bit clunky  to me. The fact that path names are written in special comments seems very not-PHP to me. I'd stray away from this, and I wouldn't call it the perfect framework, but it's certainly a start. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the awesome response you really covered it. I usually stray away from frameworks unless it saves me a lot time. But I will definitely check out Recess.

Comment: I too was searching for tips on the server side implementation of RESTful URLs. I had suspected Front Controller was involved so thanks for clarity. This is a great answer.

Comment: @Bailey Parker :: The Link to the Recess PHP Framework you provided, does not work anymore: "NOTICE: This domain name expired on 10/29/2017 and is pending renewal or deletion."

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:
Put this in the htaccess file at the root of your website.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule api/(.*)$ api/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule (recipe/.*) api/app.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

And then if you go to the page http://localhost/api/person/susan
You will see that it takes you to the file at http://localhost/api/api.php
I also have a recipe page that I go to using http://localhost/recipe/edit/2
Put this in the api.php file:

```
<?php
$requestParts = explode('/',$_GET['request']);
$category = $requestParts[0];
$action = $requestParts[1];
$data = $requestParts[2];
if($category == 'recipe'){
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pages/add_recipe.php');
}
```

The variables above will hold the category: recipe, action: add or edit, and the data which can be a number which is the id for the recipe or what ever you want it to be. Then inside the add_recipe.php use the variables to determine whether you are editing or adding a recipe. And if you use the api you can include different files depending on what ajax request you are using to talk to your api.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/?$ getdata.php?para1=$1&para2=$2 [NC]
```