# How do i setup the server files for a simple Rest API in php

Tags: php, web-services, rest, webserver

I'm trying to create a simple REST web service in PHP.  I only have a basic understanding of PHP, but from the documents I've so far read, there is one part I don't understand

Assuming I have a web services on the following links (GET)

> ```
> /myServer/user               --> list all users
> /myServer/user/John          --> lists John's info
> /myServer/projects           --> lists projects
> ```

How should my files on the server be set up to handle this?  Entering the link `http://localhost/myServer/user/` tells me the file doesn't exist so do I need to create different `index.php` files at the various paths to handle this?

Comment: you should take a look at apache url rewrite
http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/8291744/452584

Comment: Ok. Its so odd that many of the REST tutorials didn't mention URL re-writing. Thanks, I will check this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer = Url re-writing as mentioned in the comments.