# Logical and Physical URLs

Tags: php, html, web-services, rest, dynamic

This question is as an extension to my previous question here: ["Is this web service Restfull"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49832/what-qualifies-as-a-rest-web-service) to an attempt to better understand the concept of a Rest Web Service.
I read almost everything there is to be read about Rest and yet i am not able to understand if a certain Web Service is Rest or not , or why its not. The way i see it , everything is and is not Rest depending on the point of view...

I read in a very interesting article something that may at last make me understand what is Rest. I read that Rest doesnt use physical urls but logical ones.

I remember once i was developing an iOS application where we had to register/subscribe a user etc and i was told to make a certain Post HTTP request to our server to a URL that looked like this: `www.myServer/devices/device/register`. In the body of this request i had all the information in json format that the server needed. By that time the server for me was a black box so i didnt even care what this link meant or how it was generated. But i knew it was a web Rest service.

This month i started devepong a mobile hybrid app , where i started to develop in native code + jquery mobile for the front end , and php + mysql for the  back end. I have more or less the same scenario here where the user needs to subscribe in an event or not. When he presses a button to subscribe to a specific event , i make an http post request with ajax call and a json file in the body , to a specific php script and that script writes/updates/deletes in the database accordingly.

The call looks something like this :

```
$.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: "http://192.168.4.113/Server_CityInfo/subscribe.php",
                         data: data,
                         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         //dataType: "json",
                         success: function(response) {
                             $.mobile.changePage( "dialog.html", { role: "dialog" } );
                         },
                         error: function(xhr, status, message) { alert("Status: " + status + "\nMessage: " + message); }
                    });
```

As you see i do use a physical url , to point to my php script to take that action. Even the html page that the user is in , is a physical page! Is a page like myUrl.com/eventX .

Does that mean that this web service i am building is not a Rest one?

How did they last year point me to logical URLs and i can only point to physical php scripts? I know that their server was in java , maybe thats why the urls dont look physical?

And in the end of the day lets say i have a 100 different events that the user can subscribe to. Of course i wouldnt make a 100 static html pages. BUT i would make 1 html page that would be dynamically generated. But still the link to that page would be physical like `mySite.com/event.html`. The only way i know to make a url to look logical is when u have an index.html file inside a folder and you point to that folder so that the url looks like `myWebsite.com/myFolder`.

So the question here is , how to build a logical url and is this what makes a service Restfull?

### EDIT

---

Another thing that i read a lot is that Rest is using urls that describe resources and not operations!. Again though i fail to understand. For everything in my web service i use Post Request. I want for example to subscribe a user to an event , i make a post request at the url `my.server.com/subscribe.php` and in the body of this request i have a json file with the `id` of the user and the `event name` .

When i want to register a user i make a post request at the url `my.server.com/register.php` and a json in the body with the `id` of the user.

Is this scenario Rest and if not what is missing?

Comment: Mr @Darrel Miller i would appreciate it , if you could give me your thoughts on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain REST as I understand.

RESTfull webservices are based on two factors:

1. URLS - The urls should be based on the resources. Like: /app/students, /app/students/{id}
2. METHODS - The method defines the operation to be done on the url. Like

   - `GET` - To get resource
   - `PUT` - To insert a record
   - `POST` - To update a record
   - `DELETE` - To delete a record.

There are ways to achieve restful urls using PHP see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291712/using-clean-urls-in-restful-api)

Comment: 2 questions. In what kind of file does /app/students refer to? I write .html pages , i write .js scripts , i write .php scripts. In what kind of file does this refer to? This is what is confusing me. And also for example lets say you have an application and everytime it starts you register the user to your server with a static id and a token that can be changed in the client side. So u send everytime to a php script with a POST request a json file with id and token. The php script sees if there is a need to update or not the database. Is this rest?I use POST cause the database knows what to do

Comment: I dont use GET or PUT or DELETE as the .php script is going to understand what needs to be done. This is not REST behavior? For example if a user tries to subscribe to an event that is already subscribed nothing will happen in the database. If he tries to unsubscribe there will be a delete. If he tries to subscribe it will be an update. But the database knows users previous state and users current state (which is sent through json) and decide what action to take.