# How to generate the logical URL that is used in Rest

Tags: php, web-services, rest

I see every time that when we have a Rest web service the URLs are logical and not physical. Eg you see a POST request to a `myServer.com/user/id` and never for example a `.php` extension or whatever technology has been used.

In my web service all the requests are to physical URLs that is PHP scripts. Am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just your web service isn't REST, there are many way to perform a web service using different technologies :

```
    .SOAP
    .XML-RPC
    .Zend_Rest(if you are familiar with zend-framework)
    .Rest
    .....
```

some  are pure protocols while others are just "conventions" ..
then the answer to your question is: No you are not doing anything wrong.

Comment: Timmz Thank you very much. Since you seem to know what you are talking about could you take a look at this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209809/logical-and-physical-urls . How would u call this web service? Is it rest or not?

Comment: What makes my web service not a Restfull one? I completely fail to understand it :(

Comment: as I understand REST:sine a url contain .php or something like: site.com/parm1=1?&email=..., then it's not REST: cause REST is "designed in a way to use "Clean" Urls.please check this website it explains things very well: http://microformats.org/wiki/rest/urls