# Using "?" when rewriting the URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been researching for weeks now looking how to rewritting this file/directory with a complementary "?" or "question mark"

What I need:

```
http://mydomain.com/demo01.php
```

to look like:

```
http://mydomain.com/?theme=jerus
```

*theme* > is just a simple directory I need to use for my websites products(in this case themes)
*jerus* > it is simply the name of the theme

Extra Info:

```
I plan on rewritting every URL individually so refrain from wildcard varibles.**
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easy to instead of doing URL rewriting just put your php in a directory called theme and name it index.php?

```
http://mydomain.com/theme/?t=jerus
```

but if you're already re-writing URLs you could make a rule to acutally make it route like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/theme/jerus/
```

Which is waaaay prettier

See this question: [Using Clean URLs in RESTful API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291712/using-clean-urls-in-restful-api)