# How to access query string parameters after "Cleaning" your PHP REST API?

Tags: php, .htaccess, api, rest

To give some context, I initially started out with my api looking like this:

```
http://myserver/api.php?action=projects
```

In my api.php file I have a simple if statement to detect the action, and then react accordingly:

```
if (isset($_GET["action"])
{
    switch($_GET["action"])
    {
        case "projects"
          dostuff();
        break;
        case "otherstuff"
          dootherstuff();
        break;
       ...
    }
}
```

However, I of course wanted to clean this up, so I could go to this url:

```
http://myserver/api.php/projects
```

and get the same outcome.  I was able to accomplish this by reading up on a previous SO post:

[Using Clean URLs in RESTful API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291712/using-clean-urls-in-restful-api)

And ultimately got it working by making an .htaccess file in my root directory and using the rewrite engine like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^action/([^/\.]+)/?$ api.php?action=$1 [L]
```

This worked great!  Except for one problem, because I am using the clean URL, it no longer seems to recognize the GET parameter exists.

I've found I can use
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

And then parse the URL to get my parameters.  I don't see how this could work out though once I start introducing multiple parameters.  Is there something I'm missing here, or do I need to look at it a different way and change how I format the parameters instead?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your problem clearly. Can you clarify a bit more on what exactly isn't working.

Comment: @anubhava The problem is that when I use the clean url, the global variable $_GET is empty in my api.php.  However I would still like to access the query parameters without having to parse $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] which contains the whole request string.  Does that clear it up at all?

Comment: For which URI you don't get `$_GET` array?

Comment: @anubhava http://myserver/api.php/projects

Comment: For `http://myserver/api.php/projects` which `$_GET` parameter should be available?

Comment: @anubhava projects.  If you look at my first url I am actually using `http://myserver/api.php?action=projects`.  But I am using the rewrite rule to make it show up as the cleaner version `http://myserver/api.php/projects`.  The `$_GET` parameter is only available when using the first URI, even though they both technically use that one as far as I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?:action|api\.php)/([^/.]+)/?$ api.php?action=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Looks like I get a 404 error when trying to access the `http://myserver/api.php/projects` after changing the rule to this.

Comment: ok try to make it `api.php?action=$1 [L,NC,QSA]` instead of `/api.php?action=$1 [L,NC,QSA]` above

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^action/([^/\.]+)/?$ api.php?action=$1 [L, QSA]
```

You need the QSA parameter to keep the querystring intact. So now this is possible:

```
/action/projects/?my=name
```

Or you can do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^action/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ api.php?action=$1&method=$2 [L, QSA]
RewriteRule ^action/([^/\.]+)/?$ api.php?action=$1 [L, QSA]
```

Now you will have these urls:

```
/action/projects/add/
/action/projects/
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Niels.  However I'm not quite sure this is what I'm after.  Rather than having /action/projects/add/ I want to just send a POST/GET request to /action/projects/ or GET/PUT on /action/projects/id.  I tried your second example and I get INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 500 after making that change.  I removed the L flag from the first rule, however from what I understand about the Apache rewrite_mod the output of the first rule will be applied to the second rule right?

Comment: The first one matching will be used. The space between L and QSA might be needed to remove. I'm not sure why this gives an error. It should work.