# Rewrite ?search=query to /search/query and pagination

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, pagination

My method within the controller can receive this:

> domain.com/busqueda/anything

That will search within my database for'anything' and paginate the results, so if more than one then a 3rd value is needed:

> domain.com/busqueda/anything/10

The '10' will be the offset.

Using a form with GEt method will result in:

> domain.com?busqueda=anything

Which my controller won't accept. So i need to rewrite it to:

> domain.com/busqueda/anything/

And be able as well to accept the offset value when typed or linked directly like:

> domain.com/busqueda/anything/10

I'm pretty bad when htaccess comes. I have tried some rules but only worked with no 'offset'.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to create some sort of rudimentary REST API. Let me know if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291712/using-clean-urls-in-restful-api.

Comment: Hi Jason, not really. Just want to rewrite the query to, let's say, a friendly URL so it can be parsed by my controller with the added offset value which is what throws me off because without it the rewrite would be easy to figure it out. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make another controller method for form, where you'll get GET parameter and make a redirect: redirect('busqueda/'.$this->input->get('busqueda'));

---

### In case of having problems with routing:

In application/config/routes.php add:

```
$route['busqueda/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'busqueda_controller/busqueda_method/$1/$2';
$route['busqueda/(:any)'] = ''busqueda_controller/busqueda_method/$1';
```

In you busqueda_controller/busqueda_method just make:

```
$offset = false; //no offset

if(FALSE !== $this->uri->segment(3)) {
    $offset = (int)$this->uri->segment(3); //I've used casting, because I don't know how CI does it. Maybe it's unnecessary here
}
```

Comment: Thanks jacekpl. However routes and pagination are working perfectly, my problem comes when trying to use a form to do a search, which will format the URL with query strings like I mentioned, so the controller won't take that. That's why I need to rewrite the URL in that case so the controller gets it. Hope is clearer now.

Comment: You can make another controller method for form, where you'll get GET parameter and make a redirect: redirect('busqueda/'.$this->input->get('busqueda'));

Comment: Clever idea jacekpl! Working perfectly, just needed to change the config from QUERY_STRING to AUTO to get the string. Thanks!