# mod_rewrite API paths

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to configure an APACHE virtual server hosted as `api.myapp.com` hosting a PHP application.

The routes of the PHP application are

```
/* -> HTML
/api/* -> JSON
```

So the same Apache instance also host a `app.myapp.com`, which just serves up HTML.

Both `app.myapp.com` and `api.myapp.com` point to `public/` of the PHP application directory. What I'd like to do is this: all requests coming into `api.myapp.com/<method>` get rewritten to `api.myapp.com/api/<method>` but I'm afraid I've had no success yet.

Here's what I came up with in the server config section:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} api
   RewriteRule ^ http://api.%{HTTP_HOST}%/api/{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>
```

**EDIT: My .htaccess looks like;**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.myapp\.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api
    RewriteRule ^ /api%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you turned on the rewrite engine? What is the error? What means 'no success'? Does the server not start or is the redirection simply failing?

Comment: I do think the rewrite engine is on, I checked and saw rewrite rules in the .htaccess file too. There is no error, the rewrite just fails without changing anything.

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291712/using-clean-urls-in-restful-api Use RewriteRule ^/api/ api.php or RewriteRule ^/api/([^\.]+).(xml|json|atom) api.php?url=$1&type=$2 to send all requests to one api.php file and then process the quest with that php file.

Answer (score 1):

Both the previous solutions are partially correct. Combine the two as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.myapp\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api
RewriteRule ^ /api%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: I've added an edit to my question containing what the .htaccess file looks like. I hope that helps. Your solution still causes a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/api%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

1. It is better to use more specific rules: ^api - host starts with api
2. **api.** is not needed. HTTP_HOST already contains **api.**
3. Use %{REQUEST_URI} instead of {REQUEST_URI}
4. REQUEST_URI already contains first **/** sign

Do not forget about RewriteEngine on

Comment: That broke my configuration, now I have a redirect loop and it keeps appending `api` to the path. Ex: `/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/api/v1/get-update?`

Answer (score 0):

Building upon Viktors answer, try to extend the rewrite condition.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !api
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/api%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried that but I get `RewriteCond: unknown flag 'AND'` and Apache restart fails. Any ideas?

Comment: oh sorry, the AND is implicit, I've updated the answer